# Circe - How do I specify an encoder for an extra type?

Tags: scala, circe

I made a simple modification to the example given here: https://circe.github.io/circe/, adding the type Basics. Why won't this run?

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._


class Basics(Name:String,Cached:Boolean)

sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(basics:Basics,xs: Vector[String]) extends Foo
case class Qux(basics:Basics,i: Int, d: Option[Double]) extends Foo

val foo: List[Foo] = List(Qux(new Basics("Cat",true),13, Some(14.0)),Bar(new Basics("Cat",true),Vector("cat")))
val json = foo.asJson.noSpaces
println(json)

val decodedFoo = decode[List[Foo]](json)
println(decodedFoo)
```

I'm specifically getting:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:11: error: could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: circe.this.Encoder[List[ScalaFiddle.this.Foo]]
val json = foo.asJson.noSpaces
               ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:11: error: not enough arguments for method asJson: (implicit  encoder: circe.this.Encoder[List[ScalaFiddle.this.Foo]])circe.this.Json.
Unspecified value parameter encoder.
val json = foo.asJson.noSpaces
               ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:14: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type circe.this.Decoder[List[ScalaFiddle.this.Foo]]
val decodedFoo = decode[List[Foo]](json)
```

Extra magic:

```
sealed trait Bat
case class Basics(name:String,cached:Boolean) extends Bat
```

fixes it. Why?

As does

```
 case class Basics(name:String,cached:Boolean)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Basics` needs to be a `case class` to auto-derive the decoder.

Circe is based on shapeless to do the auto-derivation, and shapeless works with case classes, not with plain classes.

As a rule of thumb in Scala, if your class represents some kind of record/data, use case class.